# Split JSON array into separate files/objects

Tags: json, posix, jq

I have JSON exported from Cassandra in this format.

```
[
  {
    "correlationId": "2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8",
    "leg": 0,
    "tag": "received",
    "offset": 263128,
    "len": 30,
    "prev": {
      "page": {
        "file": 0,
        "page": 0
      },
      "record": 0
    },
    "data": "HEAD /healthcheck HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
  },
  {
    "correlationId": "2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8",
    "leg": 0,
    "tag": "sent",
    "offset": 262971,
    "len": 157,
    "prev": {
      "page": {
        "file": 10330,
        "page": 6
      },
      "record": 1271
    },
    "data": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Wed, 14 Feb 2018 12:57:06 GMT\r\nServer: \r\nConnection: close\r\nX-CorrelationID: Id-2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8 0\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\n\r\n"
  }]
```

I would like to split it to separate documents:

> {
>           "correlationId": "2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8",
>           "leg": 0,
>           "tag": "received",
>           "offset": 263128,
>           "len": 30,
>           "prev": {
>             "page": {
>               "file": 0,
>               "page": 0
>             },
>             "record": 0
>           },
>           "data": "HEAD /healthcheck HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
>         }

and

> {
>           "correlationId": "2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8",
>           "leg": 0,
>           "tag": "sent",
>           "offset": 262971,
>           "len": 157,
>           "prev": {
>             "page": {
>               "file": 10330,
>               "page": 6
>             },
>             "record": 1271
>           },
>           "data": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Wed, 14 Feb 2018 12:57:06 GMT\r\nServer: \r\nConnection: close\r\nX-CorrelationID:
>   Id-2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8 0\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\n\r\n"
>         }

I wanted to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/%20JQ) but didn't find way how.

Can you please advise way, how to split it by the document separator?

Thanks, Reddy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a JSON file into separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744361/split-a-json-file-into-separate-files)

Comment: Do you need it to work for an arbitrary number of documents, or specifically for two documents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using jq, one can split an array into its components using the filter:

```
.[]
```

The question then becomes what is to be done with each component. If you want to direct each component to a separate file, you could (for example) use jq with the -c option, and filter the result into awk, which can then allocate the components to different files. See e.g. [Split JSON File Objects Into Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500569/split-json-file-objects-into-multiple-files)

#### Performance considerations

One might think that the overhead of calling jq+awk would be high compared to calling python, but both jq and awk are lightweight compared to python+json, as suggested by these timings (using Python 2.7.10):

```
time (jq -c  .[] input.json | awk '{print > "doc00" NR ".json";}')
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.008s

time python split.py
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.046s
```

Answer (score 9):

To split a json with many records into chunks of a desired size I simply use:

```
jq -c '.[0:1000]' mybig.json
```

which works like python slicing.

See the docs here: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

> Array/String Slice: .[10:15]
>
> The .[10:15] syntax can be used to return
>   a subarray of an array or substring of a string. The array returned by
>   .[10:15] will be of length 5, containing the elements from index 10
>   (inclusive) to index 15 (exclusive). Either index may be negative (in
>   which case it counts backwards from the end of the array), or omitted
>   (in which case it refers to the start or end of the array).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it more efficiently using Python (because you can read the entire input once, instead of once per document):

```
import json

docs = json.load(open('in.json'))

for ii, doc in enumerate(docs):
    with open('doc{}.json'.format(ii), 'w') as out:
        json.dump(doc, out, indent=2)
```

Comment: @JohnZwinck - If you mean more efficient than multiple invocations of jq, perhaps you could say so, though for N=2, my timings indicate that for the specific data provided by the OP, your python solution is overall more than five times slower than the twice-jq solution.

Comment: @peak: Nobody cares about the performance of a degenerate case like N=2.  Can you try it with N=10000, please?

Answer (score 2):

In case you have an array of 2 objects:

```
jq '.[0]' input.json > doc1.json && jq '.[1]' input.json > doc2.json
```

Results:

```
$ head -n100 doc[12].json
==> doc1.json <==
{
  "correlationId": "2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8",
  "leg": 0,
  "tag": "received",
  "offset": 263128,
  "len": 30,
  "prev": {
    "page": {
      "file": 0,
      "page": 0
    },
    "record": 0
  },
  "data": "HEAD /healthcheck HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
}

==> doc2.json <==
{
  "correlationId": "2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8",
  "leg": 0,
  "tag": "sent",
  "offset": 262971,
  "len": 157,
  "prev": {
    "page": {
      "file": 10330,
      "page": 6
    },
    "record": 1271
  },
  "data": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Wed, 14 Feb 2018 12:57:06 GMT\r\nServer: \r\nConnection: close\r\nX-CorrelationID: Id-2232845a8556cd3219e46ab8 0\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\n\r\n"
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `jq '. | length' input.json` to get the number of documents, then loop that many times.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, before making such statements you should have elaborated that moment with OP ; in case you're considering that moment as critical. Anyway, I don't think such behavior is reputable for 126K contributor. I'm disappointed

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using jq's stream option and piping that to the split command

```sh
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' bigfile.json | split -l $num_of_elements_in_a_file - big_part
```

The number of lines per file varies according to the value that you put into num_of_elements_in_a_file,

You can check out this answer [Using jq how can I split a very large JSON file into multiple files, each a specific quantity of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808581/using-jq-how-can-i-split-a-very-large-json-file-into-multiple-files-each-a-spec#)
which refers to this page for a discussion on how to use the streaming parser
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#streaming-json-parser

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another example.
jq -c '.[0:10]' large_json.json > outputtosmall.json

Comment: You can format your code using ` character.