# how to accomplish each_slice like ruby with jq

Tags: jq

Sample Input

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

My Solution

```
$ echo '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]' | jq --arg g 4 '. as $l|($g|tonumber) as $n |$l|length as $c|[range(0;$c;($g|tonumber))]|map($l[.:.+$n])' -c
```

Output

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9]]
```

shorthand, handy method anything else?

Comment: There are some answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412721/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks-with-jq

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop to chop off the first 4 elements `.[4:]` until the array is empty `[]`. Then, for each result array, consider only its first 4 items `[:4]`. Generalized to `$n`:

```sh
jq -c --argjson n 4 '[while(. != []; .[$n:])[:$n]]'
```

```json
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9]]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WcP86BCN-G)

Comment: Thank you response. This is very cool solution...

Answer (score 1):

One way using `reduce` operating on the whole list, forming only `n` entries (sub-arrays) at a time

```
jq -c --argjson g 4 '. as $input | 
  reduce range(0; ( $input | length ) ; $g) as $r ( []; . + [ $input[ $r: ( $r + $g ) ] ] )'
```

The three argument form of `range(from: upto; by)` generates numbers from to upto with an increment of by

E.g. `range(0; 9; 4)` from your original input produces a set of indices - `0, 4, 8` which is ranged over and the final list is formed by appending the slices, coming out of the array slice operation e.g. `[0:4]`, `[4:8]` and `[8:12]`

Comment: Instead of having `reduce` successively build up the array, you could also directly collect the fragments in a superordinate array, which would render unnecessary saving the input in a variable: `jq --argjson g 4 '[range(0; length; $g) as $r | .[$r:$r+$g]]'`

Comment: @pmf I like using `reduce`, but yeah the above is much shorter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's an undocumented builtin function, `_nwise/1`, which you would use like this:

```
jq -nc --argjson n 4 '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | [_nwise($n)]'

[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9]]
```

Notice that using `--argjson` allows you to avoid the call to `tonumber`.

Comment: thank you for answering.I had never heard of _nwise before!